# Application for calculating distance and elevation from GPX file?

Tags: maps, gps

Is there an application that could import GPX file and calculate travelled distance and elevation made? Such as Endomondo or RunKeeper are doing that online? I have some GPX files recorded on GPS device, I'd like to visualise and analise the workout made by me.

Comment: Have you tried Google Earth?

Comment: @neogeomat once very long ago. I wasn't aware they have such functionality. Could you answer with some screenshots and details?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gpx2kml.com](http://gpx2kml.com)

After conversion you have the statistics as the one bellow. You can also store your tracks and it's free of charge.

[image: Sample of GPX track Statistics]

Comment: Do you know, what is the source of the elevation data in that application?

Comment: As far as I know, GPX files have the elevation attached to each of their coords. 
I know some of them miss the time, but I never had one with no elevation.

Comment: Well, that limits the usability of the application to me, because GPS devices usually measure elevation imprecisely, and there are terrible 'jumps' sometimes... Nevertheless, nice to know the alternatives to Endomondo

Comment: I believe that you need some app/service that works on "corrections", to fix some "out of range" values, based on some complicated algorithm.
If you find it, let me know. I also use Endomondo and I believe I run/bike a lot more than it says :))

Answer (score 0):

**GPSVisualizer** has a couple tools/solutions available here:

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation

You can upload a .GPX file, and it can either append elevation data or visualize the elevation over distance for you

[image: GPX Logger]

Sample Visualization:

[image: Sample Elevation Map]

They also provide an [Elevation Lookup Utility](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/elevation.html) leveraging the Google Maps API